# Fetching YouTube video list in Titanium

Tags: android, video, youtube, xml-parsing, titanium

I am newbie in Titanium and trying to fetch video lists of a particular channel from YouTube using [THIS](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1-SBFGbnwLRSSG_oluaGsLw6FarO-QmnxzLxtgIap708) tutorial.

The problem is, all time i get "No videos were found for this search" message(used inside catch exception) and from Chrome console i get the exception message:

**"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin localhost:8020 is therefore not allowed access. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)"**

Can anyone point me out what solution would be for this problem? From some googling, i see that is not the problem inside the code, it's a server-side problem, so how can i overcome this YouTube response problem?

And i also checked that, this line `var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;` always results to null that's what no videos are found. I used instead:

```
if (!this.responseXML)
{
    //if not XML you have to convert it to XML
    doc = Titanium.XML.parseString(this.responseText).documentElement;       
}
else
{
    //if it is XML, then just set the doc variable
    doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;
}
```

Still **doc** is null alltime! Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Looks like you are making AJAX request to wrong domain. Update your question with whole code example which replicates your issue, to get full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i solved the problem. In fact that was a browser issue, when i tested in desktop, browser uses **localhost:8020** as the address and YouTube didn't response back for that address.

Later, i tested it a real android device and voila!, it works..`var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement`clearly contains the responseXML and then it extract video information by `var items = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry")`.

Hope that could help someone someday!